# Finding names of people who work on a specific project number

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to find the names and addresses of all employees who work on at least one project located in Houston but whose department has no location in Houston. My database schema and table data looks like this: [schema design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7uTh.jpg), [table data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X62qo.png). My code for this assignment is as follows

```
SELECT e.Fname, e.Minit, e.Lname, e.Address
FROM EMPLOYEE AS e
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM WORKS_ON AS w, PROJECT AS p
WHERE w.Essn=e.SSN AND p.Plocation=w.Pno AND p.Plocation='Houston')
AND
NOT EXISTS
(SELECT * FROM DEPT_LOCATIONS AS dl 
WHERE dl.Dlocation=e.Dno AND dl.Dlocation='Houston')
```

From looking at the table data, the name that should come up is "Jennifer S Wallace," however my query yields no results.

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try this (didn't test it though):

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    employee e
INNER JOIN
    works_on as w ON e.San = w.Essn
INNER JOIN
    project p ON w.Pno = p.Pnumber AND p.Plocation = 'Houston'
INNER JOIN
    department d ON e.Dno = d.Pno
INNER JOIN
    dept_locations dl ON d.Pno = dl.Dnumber AND dl.Dlocaion != 'Houston'
```